# Adding a PNG to AI but it comes across with a white backgroud

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png, background, import

Im sure this is a simple one and I have just changed a setting on AI but for a week now PNGs won't come across without a white square background?

Any one have any ideas?

Comment: Does the PNG actually have transparency? Not all PNGs do! Have you checked it in Photoshop?

Answer (score 1):

Something similar used to happended to me, but with a black bg instead of white. This happeneded to me when I pasted an image directly by copying it from the internet, try to download it and place it the image, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

PNG files are suitable for wide usage and support transparency. In other words, they can be transparent or not. If the png file is not transparent, you should download it and remove its background in Photoshop or Corel PhotoPaint before you put it into AI. You can use all available tools for selecting and erasing as soon as you have converted the image to a layer, not the background.

Your second option: Once you copied the png file directly to AI, draw a clipping mask that hides the background and other unwanted areas. You can edit the nodes of the drawn mask perfect before you apply it.